# MMIX: questions on dynamic trap

Tags: exception, architecture, interrupt, knuth, mmix

I have some questions on MMIX's interrupt.
The definition of the special register rK is "interrupt mask register".
But it seems it treat different event differently.

- for I/O bits(let's call ** bit:
   This is a normal case.
   When an external interrupt come, if rK's ** bit is 0, rQ's ** bit will hold '1' until rK's ** bit is set to 1, and the trap will occur.
- for S-bit (program):
   Accroding to the source-code of `mmix-pipe`, even when rK's S-bit is 0, a security exception will occur. and rK's S-bit will be alter from 0 to 1.
   So, in positive-address, rK's S-bit should be 1, and in negative-address rK's S-bit don't have any effect.
   Only rQ's S-bit is used to tell system that "there was a security issue", rK's S-bit seems useless.
- for P-bit (program):
   It is sad "instruction comes from a privileged (negative) virtual address." in mmix-doc.pdf.
   But if PC is in a negative-address, rQ's P-bit will not always be set to 1. (mmix-pipe also not set rQ's P-bit). 

  I can prove it:
   If all the instructions that executed before the "resume" insn will set rQ's P-bit to 1, then resume will also set rQ's P-bit to 1.
   As a result, after the resume, the 'user' insn will always trigger a TRAP. that is impossible.
   So when P-exception is inhibited, rQ's P-bit will not set to 1.

   so rK's P-bit is not just used as a mask, it is used as a "option to bypass a exception-checking".

---

Here are some questions.

- Why not make all rK's bits just as a mask for interrupt? Is there any reason made S/P bits so strange?
- do other rQ's program bits (rwxnkb) set to 1 if rK's corresponding bits is 0?
- As in Neg-address, trip will not occur, do DVWIOUZX bits hold 1 after it just happened?